# Inserting a variable into jQuery .css

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript Variable that stores the width of an element ,called popupWidth, in px, e.g. '200px'. The '' are part of the variable, because jQuery needs them.
How can I insert the variable into jQuerys .css?

```
$(this).css({
   width: + popupWidth,
});
```

The code above doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the jQuery .css() man page...
http://api.jquery.com/css/

It shows that you have to enter the css attributes as essentially a JSON type datastructure... not as just pure text.

```
$(this).css({ width : popupWidth });
```

the above should work for you as you have 'already' added the px to the popupWidth variable